# How to notify my server application?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, push-notification, synchronization, activemq-classic

I'm sending some files, periodically, to my `bucket` on `Amazon S3`. However, I need to **notify** my **servers** that my bucket was **updated**, so they can **download** the new files.

I would like to implement a **push** and **pull** approach, or something like that.
I'm thinking about bulding an `ActiveMQ` environment, to work with `topics`. Nevertheless, I wonder if it's **really necessary**, maybe I'm overreacting with this problem and you guys might have a simpler solution for this.

**[EDIT]**

I have been trying to do something really simple with `shell`, so far I got this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

CLIENTID=$(hostname -f)
MOM_ADDRESS="mom.company.solutions"
DESTINATION="Company.Product.Sync"
TYPE="topic"

USER="admin"
PASSWORD="admin"

# USER="user"
# PASSWORD="user"

produce(){
    curl -u "${USER}":"${PASSWORD}" -d "body=${MESSAGE}" "http://${MOM_ADDRESS}:8161/api/message/${DESTINATION}?type=${TYPE}"
}


consume(){
    while [ true ];
    do
        wget --user "${USER}" --password "${PASSWORD}" "http://${MOM_ADDRESS}:8161/api/message/${DESTINATION}?type=${TYPE}&clientId=${CLIENTID}"
        sleep 5
    done
}

case "${1}" in
    produce)
        MESSAGE="${2}"
        produce
        ;;
    consume) 
        consume
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: jasper {produce|consume}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Usage:

```
./queue produce './sync download'
./queue consume
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enable S3 event notifications: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

You can have those go to an SNS topic, an SQS queue, or a Lambda function.

Comment: Great tip Mark! Thanks!